# Using System.Drawing.Font Object as Itextsharp Basefont

Tags: c#, fonts, drawing, itext

Im trying to write text to a PDF using ITEXTSHARP.
Currently i use Basefont,but the number of fonts is limited.Is there any way i can use Normal System.Drawing.Fonts with Itextsharp?

```
var font = BaseFont.CreateFont(BaseFont.TIMES_BOLD, BaseFont.WINANSI, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
var overContent = stamper.GetOverContent(index);
overContent.SetFontAndSize(font, fontSize);
```

Comment: That is not possible.  You are not stuck with the predefined fonts, use the CreateFont() overload that takes a string.

Answer (score 3):

You first need to register the font with the FontFactory, to get the base font of any System.Drawing.Font. Something like this would suffice:

```
    string fontsFolder = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0}\\Fonts", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SystemRoot"));
    FontFactory.RegisterDirectory(fontsFolder);
    BaseFont myBaseFont = FontFactory.GetFont(mySysDrawFont.OriginalFontName, mySysDrawFont.Size, ConvertFontStyle(mySysDrawFont.Style)).BaseFont;

    private static int ConvertFontStyle(FontStyle fontStyle)
    {
        switch (fontStyle)
        {
            case FontStyle.Regular:
                return Font.NORMAL;

            case FontStyle.Bold:
                return Font.BOLD;

            case FontStyle.Italic:
                return Font.ITALIC;

            case FontStyle.Underline:
                return Font.UNDERLINE;

            case FontStyle.Strikeout:
                return Font.STRIKETHRU;

            default:
                return Font.UNDEFINED;
        }
    }
```

Just bear in mind that you should call the *RegisterDirectory* function only once, not every time, so the way done above is only an example.